# How to track mailto: as a goal in Piwik?

Tags: matomo

I'm using Piwik for analytics. I need to track clicks on a `mailto:` link. What's a good way to track this? I tried creating a goal "Click on a Link to an external website" and "where the external website URL contains Pattern mailto:". Doesn't seem to work.

[image]

I found [this](http://www.statstory.com/tracking-events-in-google-analytics/#mailto-ga) for Google Analytics. I hope it's less cumbersome with Piwik.

Answer (score 2):

Use same onClick listener as mentioned in linked article and force Piwik to [track a goal manually](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#manually-trigger-goal-conversions). Would be also useful to set the goal to be triggered manually and more than once during one visit.